# Ubuntu 13.04 Screen problems

Tags: unity, 13.04, graphics, video

Okay, I haven't seen anyone else ask this question yet, but I may have just overlooked it. I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP laptop and I'm having some pretty annoying graphical problems. Sometimes, my bar at the top of the screen will just go transparent, my icons in my launch bar flicker and disappear, and if I try to play minecraft, i can't see because of the weird graphical glitches. I wish I could post images, but my rep on here isn't high enough. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post images somewhere on the web (like http://imgur.com/ or http://postimage.org/), then add links here. You can put up to 2 links in your post (until "new user restrictions" are lifted after you get a bit of rep, then it's unlimited). But if you have more, you can post them in comments. We can check out your images and add the pictures to your question for you.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what graphics card you have would be helpful.

Install your recommended graphics driver. To do so, go to 'Software & Updates', then go to the 'additional drivers' tab. Select the proprietary driver from your GPU manufacturer; preferably one that's tested if it's available, if not just install the newest one and reboot your machine.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask. If you're still having issues, come back and provide some updates on the situation.

Hope this helps! Iechyd Da!